# 2D scrolling View for Images and Buttons (on smaller screens)

Tags: java, android

How can you create larger views than the screen real-estate in Android?

I am trying to recreate a view from my iOS project in Android. The view consists of a first column of static images and then a 20x13 grid of buttons (yes that's 260 in total!) which will generate another activity when clicked:

[image: ipad screen]

Each button throws out an integer and there is a daily background image change.

The problem for phones is screen real-estate. Fitting everything on one screen makes the buttons too small to touch properly. In the iPhone app I created bigger buttons set offscreen within a ScrollView that the user could then scroll to. To my knowledge Android does not do a 2d version of ScrollView. I have tried to use gridview dynamically, for example:

[image: Grid view Example]

However, the dynamic buttons generated need to go VERTICALLY, they are too small to press on smaller screens AND it only scrolls in one direction.

I have also been thinking about 14 Vertical Linear/RelativeLayouts but again I am limited to screen dimensions which will make the buttons too small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did implement code from this [link](http://blog.gorges.us/2010/06/android-two-dimensional-scrollview/) which works perfectly well. You create a custom scrollView and then insert it within your XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/scene_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:drawingCacheQuality="low"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<com.example.yourappname.TwoDScrollView
android:id="@+id/scene_scroller"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:drawingCacheQuality="low" >

</com.example.yourappname.TwoDScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can then put your items in a layout and be sure to sort the width/height parameters to what you need - match_parent will fix your layout to the screen.